# multiple C headers included in C++ project

Tags: c++, namespaces, include, c99

I have C++ (C++17) project (let's call it "Client") where I have to connect with multiple different embedded devices.
Software for each device is written in C99 standard. Each device project has a directory like "config/" with
a header like "states.h" where are described the states of the state machine  (also some types, etc.).
In my C++ (client) project I'm fetching each of the embedded device directories as a local repo, using CMake.
The problems are:

- I have multiple C headers with the same guards `#ifndef _STATES_H_ ......` and when I compile the C++ project only one file will be
  taken into account (obvious).
- Even if I can change the guard's name (
  `_EMBDEVICE_1_STATES_H`, `_EMBDEVICE_2_STATES_H`) still (probably)
  the C++ compiler will not include two files with the same name.
- Even if  can solve both above problems, in each of these files I have
  struct and types with the same name (for example  `typedef struct state_mahine {....}` etc).

The major problem is I CAN'T modify the C files.
If I could, I could change the guard's name, I can surround content with the struct `struct embdevice_1 {  ... };` but still is the problem B)  - I have two files with the same name.

If it's possible, how can I manage this problem using CMake, and/or preprocessor?

EDIT (19.04.2023)
The source code of my embedded devices I'm fetching by `FetchContent_Declare`.
My project tree looks like:

```
my_project  
├─ CMakeLists.txt  
├─ _deps  
│  ├─ device_01-src  
│  │   ├─ src  
│  │      └─ state_mahine  
│  │         ├─ states.h  
│  │         └─ config.h
│  └─ device_02-src  
│      ├─ src  
│         └─ state_mahine  
│            ├─ states.h  
│            └─ config.h  
│
├─ devices  
│  ├─ Device_01_Driver   <-- only here including the headers from device_01
│  │  ├─ CMakeLists.txt       <-- only here I'm fetching the device_01 repo
│  │  ├─ device_01_driver.hpp 
│  │  ├─ device_01_driver.cpp  
│  ├─ Device_02_Driver   <-- only here including the headers from device_02
│  │  ├─ CMakeLists.txt       <-- only here I'm fetching the device_02 repo
│  │  ├─ device_02_driver.hpp  
│  │  ├─ device_02_driver.cpp  
│  ├─ devices.hpp  
├─ main.cpp  
├─ main.hpp
```

I'm including the files from `device_x_src` repository only from `device_x_` drivers files, and in `main` I'm including the `devices.hpp` and drivers class (my further goal is no need to include drivers in `main`, but only in the  `devices.hpp`, however, this is not the point of my problem now). So basically all of the structures etc. are encapsulated in the driver cpp files, and there's no interconnection between C repositories.
I'm not a CMake master, but maybe is a possibility to reduce the scope of  #define (workaround of _*GUARDS__H*) and variables (some workaround like using the namespaces)

Comment: `namespace foo { #include "foo.h" } namespace bar { #include "bar.h" }`

Comment: Do you need to include all of the headers in the same C++ source file (i.e. translation unit)? Or is it possible for you to compile different C++ source files for different devices, that all define device-specific classes and/or functions that are then called from a central location? (If you're worried about the code being the same for each device, you could also have trivial C++ files that just include first the device-specific headers and then a generic file that contains the C++ code that work with all headers.)

Comment: Could you try and wrangle these each into separate `namespace`?

Comment: @chris_se
 No, from my first look, It can be done without including all C headers in one Cpp file

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number
  Thanks a lot! It's so obvious, I don't know why I didn't think of this. And basically, it works. But problem B - header guards still exist, because I can't modyfy the C headers

Comment: not sure if it will, but you cannot have different classes with the same name and in c++ there are namespaces as solution

Comment: "still (probably) the C++ compiler will not include two files with the same name." - this is false

Comment: you're in luck that if this is all designed for C, there's a good chance you can sneakily include different things with the same name in different source files and the compiler won't notice you're doing it. Then you just need each of those files to export functions with *different* names...

Comment: Adding an `#include` inside a namespace only works in some cases. If other headers are included from the included files or if a symbol implemented in another translation unit is forward declared in the header, you get into trouble. As for including multiple files: The C++ compiler doesn't care about file names, but you need some way of distinguishing between them such as the containing dir; header guards can be `#undef`ed.

Answer (score 1):

From your description plus your answers in the comments, there are two components to this:

1. Actually including the files depending on their name.
2. Utilizing the files in your code.

First of all, to actually include the files, you can always reference them with explicit paths. So for example, if your devices have the following directory structure (this could be achieved via e.g. git submodules):

- `src`

  - `yoursourcefiles.cpp`
- `device1`

  - `config`

    - `state.h`
  - `somethingelse.c`
- `device2`

  - `config`

    - `state.h`
  - `anotherthingelse.c`
- ...

Then you can include the configuration files explicitly using relative paths:

`#include "../device1/config/state.h` (for `device1`), `#include "../device2/config/state.h` (for `device2`), etc.

As for the second part: Since you said you can't modify the C files themselves and they use the same include guard + define the same type names, the following would be one *possible* method of achieving this, but by no means the own.

## Variants that include the headers in separate files

First you'll need to define some kind of dispatch mechanism. In this case I'll showcase this for an abstract base class that encapsulates the device-specific functionality. For example something like the following:

```cpp
class Device {
public:
    virtual ~Device() {}
    virtual std::string readSerialNumber() const = 0;
};
```

(I have no idea what specific functionality you need, so I've restricted this to `readSerialNumber()` as an example.)

Then you'll need to have some kind of prototype for an instantiation function for each device type, plus definitions for each individual device. In this case I've chosen to use a template:

```cpp
enum class DeviceType {
    Device1,
    Device2,
    // ...
};
template<DeviceType deviceType>
std::unique_ptr<Device> instantiateDeviceImpl();

// Forward-declare all implementations for all device types:
extern template
std::unique_ptr<Device> instantiateDeviceImpl<DeviceType::Device1>();
extern template
std::unique_ptr<Device> instantiateDeviceImpl<DeviceType::Device2>();

// Generic dispatcher
inline std::unique_ptr<Device> instantiateDevice(DeviceType deviceType)
{
    switch (deviceType) {
    case DeviceType::Device1: return instantiateDeviceImpl<DeviceType::Device1>();
    case DeviceType::Device2: return instantiateDeviceImpl<DeviceType::Device2>();
    default: throw std::runtime_error("Invalid device type");
    }
}
```

### Sub-variant: no common code between devices

If each of the implementations of the common class don't actually share code you can simply define different C++ implementations for each device individually. In that case you'd create a file `device1_impl.cpp` with content like the following:

```cpp
// Include the definition of the Device class
#include "device.hpp"
// Use an anonymous namespace to ensure that the data
// structures defined in the device-specific header are
// only visible to this individual source file, and use
// extern "C" because the C headers likely don't include
// that.
namespace {
extern "C" {
// Include the device specific header
#include "../device1/config/state.h"
}

class Device1Impl : public Device {
public:
    virtual ~Device1Impl() {}
    virtual std::string readSerialNumber() const
    {
        // Code that makes use of the data defined in the header
    }
};

template
std::unique_ptr<Device> instantiateDeviceImpl<DeviceType::Device1>()
{
    return std::make_unique<Device1Impl>();
}
```

Also create the analogous files for the other device types. This allows you to reuse the C header files of the devices.

### Sub-variant: all C++ code is shared between device types

In that case you'll want to use a different approach with the contents of `device1_impl.cpp`:

```cpp
// Define a macro that can be used by the generic code
#define IMPL_DEVICE_TYPE   Device1
// Use an anonymous namespace to ensure that the data
// structures defined in the device-specific header are
// only visible to this individual source file, and use
// extern "C" because the C headers likely don't include
// that.
namespace {
extern "C" {
// Include the device specific header
#include "../device1/config/state.h"
}
}
// Now include the generic code
#include "device.impl.hpp"
```

The file `device.impl.hpp` could then have the following contents (it's technically not a header, but if you call it `.cpp` then if you add it to the build system it will attempt to compile that file on its own, which isn't great - better to call it `.hpp`):

```cpp
#include "device.hpp"

// Define an anonymous namespace to avoid ODR violations
namespace {
class DeviceImpl : public Device {
public:
    virtual ~DeviceImpl() {}
    virtual std::string readSerialNumber() const
    {
        // Code that makes use of the data defined in the header
    }
};
}

template
std::unique_ptr<Device> instantiateDeviceImpl<DeviceType::IMPL_DEVICE_TYPE>()
{
    // This will use the DeviceImpl local to the specific device type
    return std::make_unique<DeviceImpl>();
}
```

## Variant: Include all C headers in the same file

The following may or may not work, depending on what data structures are defined in the C headers. You could use different C++ namespaces and include the files within the various namespaces:

```cpp
// Use explicitly defined namespaces to ensure that there
// are no name collisions, and use extern "C" because the
// C headers likely don't include that.
namespace device1 {
extern "C" {
// Undefine the header's guard macro
#ifdef _STATES_H_
#undef _STATES_H_
#endif
#include "../device1/config/state.h"
}
} // namespace device1
namespace device2 {
extern "C" {
// Undefine the header's guard macro
#ifdef _STATES_H_
#undef _STATES_H_
#endif
#include "../device2/config/state.h"
}
} // namespace device2
```

Then in the source file you can use all of the various names at once, i.e.
`device1::struct_type_name` for the first device type, `device2::struct_type_name` for the second device type, etc.

I would **not** recommend this variant, because if the various device-specific `state.h` headers themselves include other headers again, then you'd potentially also have to undefine those other header's guard macros, unless those headers are the same for all devices. Also you'll need to undefine any macro that the device-specific headers define themselves before including the next one (and your code may not rely on any of these macros, unless they are identical for all of the devices).

## Caution

Some additional word of caution here: if the C headers include some data types that are different on the device and on your system (e.g. `int` if often 16bit on microcontrollers, while it's typically 32bit on most desktop systems), then you'll run into issues. But even if the types themselves are the same, the alignment requirements and/or the endianness may still be different, depending on what exactly it is you're using. So be careful here.

## Side-note: device-specific repositories not subdirectories of your project

If the device source code is not a subdirectory of your project directly, but you're using CMake's `find_package()` functionality to find where the source files are located, you could export the include path of the device-specific projects with device-specific names (via e.g. `@cmakedefine` in a generated header + doing the include via `#include DEVICE1_INC_PATH "/config/state.h"`, where `DEVICE1_INC_PATH` would be the same of the macro you define via the build system).

## Summary

I hope this gives you some ideas on how what you're looking for can be achieved. There are of course other mechanisms you can use to perform the dispatching to different device types, the abstract base class is just a (relatively simple) method of doing this. It will depend strongly on your specific use case what abstraction is the best here.

Comment: Wow. So fast! I have to think about Your solutions. Thanks for the draft on how to hide the specific device-dependent implementation. I'm using the "variants" now and works well. However, as I know now (maybe wrong),  definitions made by `#define` are global so I can't escape from using of the directive "#undef" (of course, it's true what You wrote about nested "including")

Comment: Note that the abstract base class is only one possibility. If you only need a single function you could also just globally declare `extern int function_device1(int p); extern in function_device2(int p); inline int function_dispatch(DeviceType type, int p) { switch (type) { case DeviceType::Device1: return function_device1(p); /* ... */ } }` and then define the individual `function_device1()` etc. in their individual source files. The abstract base is useful if you want to encapsulate more than just one function, but even then there may be better options depending on the rest of your code.

Comment: Fortunately, I have to use only the states of the state machine (enum) and some other machine-dependent definitions (like max speed etc). So-  no functions.

Comment: I meant functions that you define that do something depending on the device. If for example you only need the states of the state machine, you could have a function called e.g. `get_state_list()` that is device-dependent. If I read your comment correctly, you could probably get away with defining something like `struct DeviceInfo { std::vector<...> state_list; double max_speed; /* ... */ };` and then have a device-dependent function that returns that struct for each device type, dispatched as described in my previous comment. Just some food for thought.

Comment: Please see my edited first answer, where I added an example of my project tree and rules of including.